Have Bertolt Brecht's plays been influenced by Goldoni's "La guerra"?
Even if it seems that Goldoni's play La guerra ('The War') has never been translated into English, according to the translator Alexander Gross,

the play was translated into German no fewer than five times and was performed again and again in Germany throughout the Eighteenth Century. The last of these translations was executed by Goethe's brother-in-law, and for one performance there was even a prologue composed by Goethe himself.

In his dramaturgical notes prepared in 1967 for a production of the Royal Shakespeare Company which never took place, Gross pointed out the possibility that this work by Goldoni may have had some influence on some
plays by Bertolt Brecht. He also expressed his intention to investigate this by studying Brecht's writings, but said he hadn't done so yet:

Portions of the text and action look forward to Mother Courage and the peasant scenes in some of Brecht's other plays. I have not yet checked Brecht's own writings, but it seems at least probable that he would have encountered one of the German versions at one point or another of his career.

So, my question is: have any scholar studied this? Have some Bertolt Brecht's plays been found as influenced by Goldoni's La guerra?
